# Color labels in Listplot

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, style

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

Given a `ListPlot` like this, for example:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
labels = Flatten@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10, 1}]
ListPlot[data -> labels]
```

How can I style the labels with a specific color? It kind of freaks me out that it is not possible to just use `Style` on the labels variable like this:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
labels = Style[Flatten@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10, 1}], Red]
ListPlot[data -> labels]
```

Then, no labels are shown at all.

Also, how can I increase the distance between points and corresponding labels?

I'm using mathematica: 11.0.1.0

Comment: As you've written it, the head of labels is "Style" and not "List".  Try: `labels = Style[#, Red] & /@ Flatten@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10, 1}];`

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't work either :(.

Comment: Interesting -- you seem to have different behavior than Version 11.1.  How does the following work for you?  `labels = Style[#, Red] & /@ 
  Flatten@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10, 1}]; ListPlot[
 data -> labels // Thread]`  ?

Comment: @JohnJosephM.Carrasco: Thanks again. This version plots just black labels no matter the color, although the labels variable shows red labels now. That is very strange. I restarted mathematica, but still the same problem.

Comment: Strangely, that also happens in version 10.1.0.0 on a different computer. No labels are shown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug that's been fixed in the latest version.  Compare this code in versions 11.0.1 and 11.1.1

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
labels = Map[Style[#, Red] &]@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, 10];
$VersionNumber
ListPlot[data -> labels]
```

[image]

Here is a workaround for this example

```
myStyle := Sequence[Red, Bold, FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"]
ListPlot[data -> labels] /. 
 Pane[Style[label_, {}]] :> Pane[Style[label, myStyle]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jason! That works well now :)

Comment: I've added the [tag:bugs] tag; could you maybe add the usual header in the question for me (i.e., is the `Callout[]` bug also in 11.0.0)?

Comment: @J.M. - I don't have 11.0.0 or 11.1.0 installed right now so I can't verify whether this was fixed/introduced in the main or bugfix release, also not sure about the `Callout` bug you mention, do you have a code snippet to reproduce it?

Comment: I meant the one in this answer, Jason: 11.1.1 shows the callouts, but 11.0.1 does not.

Comment: @J.M. - right, sorry for the confusion  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bit of a monster but it works

```
If[
    #1 == 1, 
    Text[Style[#1, Red], #2 + {0, .05}],
    Text[Style[#1, Blue], #2 + {0, .05}]
    ] & @@@ MapThread[List, {labels, data}] // 
 Graphics[{
    #, Point @ data
    },
   Axes -> True
   ] &
```

This code is by no means clean nor efficient :). It only serves as a demonstration that it is possible to achieve the effect you are describing.

Comment: I am getting a bit rusty with Mathematica and don't remember the pretty way to refactor the 'If' decision block using rule syntax. Anyone feeling this could be prettified, please feel free to edit the post!

Comment: That indeed works with my version, thank you! Unfortunately, it doesn't use ListPlot, so it is a bit difficult to use the other functionalities of ListPlot :(

Comment: Yeah, not fancy :P. Remember thought, all these functions do use `Graphics` implicitly. So, desired look and feel can be achieved by manipulating `Graphics` properties directly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
labels = Map[Style[ToString[#], 12, Red, Bold] &, 
   Flatten@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10, 1}]];
ListPlot[data -> labels]
```

[image]

or this:

```
labels = Map[If[# == 1, Style[ToString[#], 12, Red, Bold], 
     Style[ToString[#], 12, Blue, Bold]] &,Flatten@RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10, 1}]];
ListPlot[data -> labels]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! That is very strange. In both versions no labels are shown. I'm using mathematica 11.0.1.0, which version are you using?

Comment: @holistic Well my version is 11.1.1.0 and what I get you see on the screen. But the code uses no new features and, therefore, I have no doubts that it should work also in the previous versions. In fact the same as my first version was proposed by John Joseph M. Carrasco , only  written down in a slightly different way. For me it also works.

Comment: That is very strange, I just tried it on a different computer with version 10.1.0.0, same problem, no labels are shown.

Comment: The above implementation uses `Callout` function implicitly. This function has been introduced with version 11. Therefore, the above implementation may fail for the OP.